# How to launch Windows Slave from Linux Master in JENKINS

Tags: linux, windows, docker, jenkins

What I am trying to do: Create a Windows Slave from a Linux (Ubuntu) Master on Jenkins.

Jenkins is inside a container (Docker).

I followed the step-by-step here: https://scmquest.com/jenkins-windows-slave-configuration-with-screenshots/

And when I tried to launch the agent, I have an error like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIcQY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I find out how.

I did `docker container ls` then under PORT there's x.x.x.x:8080->8080/tcp, x.x.x.x:50000->50000/tcp. I set the port to 500000 in Jenkins->Configure Global Security->Agent.

Now I have another error from java.
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:java/sql/Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUEMt.png)